# Does AutoCloseable.close() method break Backward compatibilty rule of Java

Tags: java, java-7, try-with-resources, autocloseable

From Java 7 ,`Closeable` interface has been retrofitted to extend `AutoCloseable` interface so that all classes implementing `Closeable` interface can work with `try-with-resources` statement. Till now,Closeable interface was free to throw any exception including InterrruptedException.
  However,with Java 7 any instance of Closeable interface used in `try-with-resources` statement might throw InterruptedException when there is automatic invocation of close method after exiting the try block and its `InterruptedException` might get suppressed by implicit call to `Throwable.addSuppressed(InterruptedException);`

So does this break the backward compatibility rule of Java considering that somebody might have its exception unknowingly suppressed and program not behaving as it should

Comment: `Closeable` was not free to throw _any_ exception. It declares `IOException` as its throwables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this doesn't break backwards compatibility.  The "try-with-resources" feature was new in Java 7; old code couldn't call it.  Any old code that relies on catching an exception thrown by `close` will still be using a normal "try-catch" block, and the exception won't be suppressed because it wouldn't be using "try-with-resources".  Such a block wouldn't be able to be converted to "try-with-resources" because of the suppression, but it will still work as is.